# Access the contents of __VA_ARGS__ in a macro (not a function)

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

One can access the contents of `...` inside a function using `stdarg.h`:

```c
void fn(int nargs, ...){
  va_list args; va_start(args,nargs);
  i64 arg0 = va_arg(args,i64);
  va_end(args);
}
```

The only way I know of using `__VA_ARGS__` is to pass it to another macro or, eventually, a function. Eg.

```
#define __fn(...)  fn(number_of_args(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

but I wonder if it's possible to "unpack" the values of `__VA_ARGS__` within a macro itself. Something like `va_start()`, `va_arg()`, and `va_end()`, but for macros.

Comment: How about something like `#define HEAD(x,...)` and `#define TAIL(x,...) __VA_ARGS__`. Now you extract the head/tail with `HEAD __VA_ARGS__` and `TAIL __VA_AGS__`

Answer (score 2):

> if it's possible to "unpack" the values of **VA_ARGS** within a macro itself.

Yes, you can get the head `#define HEAD(x, ...)  x` of the pack and iterate over the list with `EVAL(EVAL(...` recursive expansion. See https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms .

I find overloading on the number of macro arguments to produce way more readable error messages than `EVAL(EVAL(..` expansions, so I prefer explicitly overloading for each argument.